# Rename text string for "definition" environment

Tags: languages, code

I want to use LaTeX in my book, which is written in my native language. Despite of using may native language package, the definition command in the template still gave the result: definition, not the translation "dinh nghia" of definition in my native language. i.e if I write :

```
\begin{definition}
This is the definition
\end{definition}
```

it should give out put that:

```
Dinh nghia 1. Day la dinh nghia.
```

but it gave me

```
Definition 1. Day la dinh nghia.
```

I use the template of Springer [which is available here](http://www.springer.com/authors/book+authors?SGWID=0-154102-12-970131-0). One of the trouble is if I write a simple code like :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
This is the definition.
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

it will give me the right answer.

My question is: What should I do to change to get the right output?

Please help me.

Comment: Can you show us a MWE with the springer template? Or to ask in another way: you have `\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}` in the preamble of your book?

Comment: I have it, and it helps me translating some other defined tags, but not all :|

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't say whether you're using `svmult` or `svmono`, but it should be similar.

In the `svmult` class you find a list of definitions for fixed tags and it's sufficient to "renew" them. For instance

```
\documentclass{svmult}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand\definitionname{Dinh nghia}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
This is the definition.
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

will give

[image]

Here is the complete list of the defined tags:

```
\def\abbrsymbname{List of Abbreviations and Symbols}
\def\abstractname{Abstract}
\def\ackname{Acknowledgements}
\def\andname{and}
\def\bibname{References}
\def\lastandname{, and}
\def\appendixname{Appendix}
\def\chaptername{Chapter}
\def\claimname{Claim}
\def\conjecturename{Conjecture}
\def\contentsname{Contents}
\def\corollaryname{Corollary}
\def\definitionname{Definition}
\def\emailname{e-mail}
\def\examplename{Example}
\def\exercisename{Exercise}
\def\figurename{Fig.}
\def\forewordname{Foreword}
\def\keywordname{{\bf Key words:}}
\def\indexname{Index}
\def\lemmaname{Lemma}
\def\contriblistname{List of Contributors}
\def\listfigurename{List of Figures}
\def\listtablename{List of Tables}
\def\mailname{{\it Correspondence to\/}:}
\def\noteaddname{Note added in proof}
\def\notename{Note}
\def\partname{Part}
\def\prefacename{Preface}
\def\problemname{Problem}
\def\proofname{Proof}
\def\propertyname{Property}
\def\propositionname{Proposition}
\def\questionname{Question}
\def\refname{References}
\def\remarkname{Remark}
\def\seename{see}
\def\solutionname{Solution}
\def\subclassname{{\it Subject Classifications\/}:}
\def\tablename{Table}
\def\theoremname{Theorem}
```

Note that some of them are already taken care of by the `vietnam` package.

However, you can define your own environment:

```
\spnewtheorem{dinh}{Dinh nghia}[section]{\bfseries}{\rmfamily}
```

so that the numbering of the definitions will be by section, using

```
\begin{dinh}
Text of the definition
\end{dinh}
```

Comment: Thank egreg for your answer, it is very helpful for me. But when I rename the definition, the definition counter is automatically changed into chapter style, i.e we have 2 definition in section 1.1, then the next definition in section 1.2 will be Definition 3, not 2.1 as usual. How can I fix it ? 
P/S : I use svmono :)

Comment: @NguyễnDuyKhánh I've added a way.

Comment: Thank you very much egreg four your edition. May I ask you a question ? how do you know the way to define a new enviroment ? What LaTex book should I read in order to knowing how ?

Comment: @NguyễnDuyKhánh `\spnewtheorem` is defined by the Springer classes (`svmono`, `svmult` and `svjour`); the documentation is in `refguide.pdf` that you should find in the ZIP file.